# How to use a function in react to change range input description

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm attempting to change the competency descriptions `this.state.competency`  based on the value the range is set to. It doesn't seem to be working. Any advice?

```
export class about extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: undefined,
          competency: ' '
        };
      }
      
      skillLevel = () => {
          if (this.state.value <= 25) {
          this.setState({
            competency: 'Novice'
          })}
          else if (this.state.value <= 50) {
          this.setState({
            competency: 'Knows things'
          })
        } else if (this.state.value <= 75) {
          this.setState({
            competency: 'Experienced'
          })
        } else if (this.state.value <= 100) {
          this.setState({
            competency: 'Expert'
          })
        }
      }
      
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label htmlFor="sales">Sales</label>
                <div className="range" skills={this.skillLevel}>
                  <p>{this.state.competency}</p>
                  <input
                    type="range"
                    min="1"
                    max="100"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    class="slider"
                    id="sales"></input>
              </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
          <div>
        )
     }
    }
    
    export default about;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to put a function directly on an element. If you want to trigger a function, it has to be through an event, take a look at the docs:

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Be careful when a state is an object and you want to update it, be sure to pass every property or to make a copy of the original state and then use the spread operator.

```html
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: undefined,
      competency: " "
    };
  }

  skillLevel = () => {
    if (this.state.value <= 25) {
      return "Novice";
    } else if (this.state.value <= 50) {
      return "Knows things";
    } else if (this.state.value <= 75) {
      return "Experienced";
    } else if (this.state.value <= 100) {
      return "Expert";
    }
  };

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
      competency: this.skillLevel()
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label htmlFor="sales">Sales</label>
            <div className="range">
              <p>{this.state.competency}</p>
              <input
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                type="range"
                min="1"
                max="100"
                value={this.state.value}
                className="slider"
                id="sales"
              ></input>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, William. I've removed the function from the div and placed the onChange you posted on the input. I'm not getting any different results. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Yes, there is. I edited my answer to make it works as I think you expect.